# FCGI htaccess handler

Tags: django, .htaccess, shared-hosting, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup django on a shared hosting provider. I followed the instructions on http://helpdesk.bluehost.com/index.php/kb/article/000531
and almost have it working.

The problem I'm facing now is that the traffic is properly routed throught the fcgi file, but the file itself shows up as plain text in the browser. If I run ./mysite.fcgi in the ssh shell, I do get the default django welcome page.

my .htaccess is:

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and mysite.fcgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import sys, os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "icm.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing AddHandler, or changing it to:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
```

Comment: Changing it to AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi in htaccess and still have the same problem (.fcgi executes on command line but shows source in browser).